# How does traverse backward work for a Doubly Linked List in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

My understanding of traversing backwards in a doubly linked list is traversing from some position back to the first node in the list. I have written a Doubly Linked List class in java, and a traverseBack method in it.

The code for the traverseBack method is as follows.

```
public void traverseBack(int d){
    for(Node n=first; n!=null; n=n.next){
        if(n.data == d){
            System.out.println("\nTraversing in Backward Direction\n");
            while(n!=null){
                System.out.println(n.data);
                n = n.prev;
            }
            return;
        }
        if(n.next==null){
            System.out.println("Given node doesn't exist");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The code was compiled and run without errors.

Can I ask whether my understanding of traversing backwards in a doubly linked list is correct or not? Is there anything in the code that I haven't done well?

Comment: Are we to assume this is a list populated with `int`?  What is `d` for?  Does that represent what you're looking for?

Comment: @tieTYT Here `d` represents from which node it starts to traverse back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake here is you do not seem to be going backward, you're going forward.  You're iterating the `Node`s in your `for` loop by calling `n=n.next`.  Shouldn't you be calling `n=n.prev`?

Why don't you just start with the `last` element and loop backwards from there?  You could go like this:

```
for(Node n=last; n!=null; n=n.prev){  //this is traversing backwards now.
```

Once you've done that, there's no need for the `while` loop at all.

Comment: the problem is in my DoublyLinkedList class I haven't defined the last node, but only the first node.

Comment: @JaneFoster Well I think you should define that.  As far as I know, it's standard to have it as a field in the implementation of a doubly linked list.  The official docs suggest that, too: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#getLast() If you don't want it as a field, you can easily create a `getLast()` method by iterating forward until you get the last.  For performance reasons, I recommend a field though.